# Are parasitic capacitance \$C_{gs}\$ and \$C_{gd}\$ parallel in a MOS?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, circuit-analysis, capacitance, circuit-design

The picutre below shows the parasitic capacitance \$C_{gs}\$ and \$C_{gd}\$ in a MOS transistor.

Can we consider that the two capacitors are in parallel in this case?

[image]

Comment: draw yourself a schematic to better visualize it

Answer (score 1):

No - they have different effects on the drive circuit.  In a power supply switching application, where you are switching a load to ground, Cgs looks like a capacitance your driver must overcome to drive the gate voltage to the "on" or "off" voltage, and for rough drive estimates, can be treated as a fixed capacitance.  Cgd is a capacitance to the drain.  When the FET is switched, the drain changes voltage rapidly, and the voltage change is capacitively coupled to the gate, so when the gate voltage is high enough to switch, the rapidly decreasing drain voltage has a tendency to drive the gate voltage back towards ground, which tends to turn the FET off.  This can cause the an oscillation on the switch that occurs at the edge of the pulse.  A similar reaction occurs when the switch is turned off.  You can see that the size of this effect depends on the voltage level being switched; switching high voltage with a FET drain produces a larger voltage coupled back to the gate.  Your driver must overcome both Cgs and the negative pulse from the drain coupled through Cgd, which will vary with the switching speed and the voltage being switched.

Answer (score 0):

No,they are not parallel (If you do not short the drain and the source).

But there values are same and it is $$C_{gs}=C_{dg}=C_{ov}W $$